# Search box to select one record from 2000 records

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am going to create a jquery ajax control for search box

search box should match each character in the text

for example typed 'er' then results like programmer employer eric derry

this control will show 10 records at a time and scrollor to scroll all other records matched.

take an example of 2000 employee name with thier ID

like 102 samual joy roy

any suggesions

please help

reply

Comment: are u looking for any jquery plugin? i used this [link](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) in one of my project

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstanding your question it seems you're looking for an autocomplete control. Take a look to [jquery-autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent example by @Claudio.. Implement his link's concept first and if you want , you can see some other examples right here..

1. http://oslund.ca/demos/ausu/
2. [Visit their demo section @ bottom & change the code in php accordingly in .net](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html)